# Return value if the value is true in python

Tags: python

I want to the return the value of the statement if it evaluates to true. For example,

```py
if f():
   return f()
elif g():
   return g()
```

The function may return a list also. since empty list evaluates to false, is there a better way to do it. I don't want to store the value outside the scope of the if statement.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. *What* do you want to happen with an empty list? And why don't you want to store the value?

Comment: If you want to return `f()` if it is _truthy_ (otherwise `g()`), then you could use `return f() or g()`. The information in your question is not very clear.

Comment: @khelwood This is true unless you don't want to return neither of `f()` or `g()` if they are not truthy (e.g. if neither of these things are true then I have to do some more work).

Comment: @khelwood your answer works good but the syntactically I was expecting something like jdehesa's answer. This is available in C++, I thought there would be a similar functionality in python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't want to return an empty list that is why I have if checks

Comment: What I think you want is `if f() is True` which will be `True` only if you get the boolean `True` back, and `False` if you get a 1 or a non-empty list.

Comment: Yes. So use `if`. I don't understand what's stopping you.

Comment: My usecase is, I have a set of functions which returns a list which can be empty. if it is empty I don't want to return and call another function. it is sure that any one of the function will return. I don't want to store the return value in a temporary.

Comment: But you haven't said why you don't want to store it in a temporary variable. That is the way to do this.

Comment: If it is certain that one of them returns a non-empty value, then `return f() or g()` would work.

Comment: Yes @DanielRoseman. return f() or g() is exactly the functionality I wanted. But I didn't know it existed. I just don't want to store it in a variable. If you had looked at the answer by jdehesa, where out is scoped inside if. if I want to store it in a temporary It's scope will be outside the if which I don't want.

Comment: Why do you tag language-lawyer?

Comment: I thought language lawyer is somebody who knows the python standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can only do:

```
out = f()
if out: return out
out = g()
if out: return out
```

But maybe what you are thinking of is something like the (controversial) [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) coming up in Python 3.8. With this you will be able to do:

```
if out := f():
    return out
elif out := g():
    return out
```